# how to keep session as normal website in angular 7?

Tags: angular, session

i am using sessionStorage but it lost when tab is closed... it should be clear on browser close...

please tell me how to do this in angular 7

i am using like below given

```
sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser',curUser);
```

in AppComponent

```
export class AppComponent {
title = 'app';
@HostListener("window:onbeforeunload",["$event"])
  clearLocalStorage(event){
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: use localStorage instead of sessionStorage and clear your cache in ```window.onbeforeunload = function(){}```

Comment: please check above code, i update my code... but it didn't worked me

Comment: Solution is to use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage`. But `localStorage` does not remove on browser close. It removes only if JavaScript code executes for removing is `localStorage.clear()` or user clears it from browser configs. What is not clear is, why do you need to keep storage on tab close and need to remove them on browser close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored in Localstorage

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser',curUser);
```

and Cleared window.onbeforeunload

```
constructor(){
  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    return false;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Local Storage to retain data for multiple tabs.
**Session Storage** - Data is stored for a session, Data is lost when tab is closed
**Local Storage** - stores data with no expiration date, and gets cleared only through JavaScript, or clearing the Browser Cache / Locally Stored Data

Try this tutorial to implement Local storage - https://alligator.io/js/introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage/

Comment: i also tried with localStorage.setItem('currentUser',curUser); exactly you said it has not expiration date... but that i need to clear on browser close